# how to create a single log file using log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, log4net

I'm using log4net in my mvc 4 project to log any error & exceptions. My configuration file looks like below

```
<appender name="AsynchronousLog4NetAppender" type="Umbraco.Core.Logging.AsynchronousRollingFileAppender, Umbraco.Core">
 <file value="App_Data\Logs\APIErrorsLog.txt"/>
 <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
 <appendToFile value="true"/>
 <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
 <maximumFileSize value="5MB"/>
 <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
</layout>
 <encoding value="utf-8"/>
</appender>
```

I have also created a view on which I read & output this file's content `App_Data\Logs\APIErrorsLog.txt` and show the errors. The issue is a new file is created every day. I guess I can increase the size using `maximumFileSize`attribute but how I can stop the creation of new file everyday?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a new file every day because you have set `<rollingStyle value="Date"/>` - use `<rollingStyle value="Size" />` to only create a new file when the maximum size is reached. You may want to also add a `maxSizeRollBackups` entry as well to limit the number of files.

Comment: Hi @stuartd If we add the rollingstyle value as Size then the conversionpattern is needed ?